# json array containing multiple objects

Tags: php, json

I want fetch multiple objects in each array but my code is showing single object what to do.
Here is my PHP Code how i add another loop to get multiple objects

```
foreach($row as $row){
$keys = $row['Cat_name'];
$output[$keys] = [];  //Creating key 
array_push($output[$keys],$row);
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

and here is result it is showing single object

```
{
"Dogs": [
    {
        "id": "127",
        "thumb_path": "/VideoWallpaper/other/other17.jpg",
        "likes": "59",
        "Downloads": "88",
        "Cat_name": "Dogs"
    }
],
"Others": [
    {
        "id": "127",
        "thumb_path": "/VideoWallpaper/other/other17.jpg",
        "likes": "59",
        "Downloads": "88",
        "Cat_name": "Others"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
$output[$keys] = [];  //Creating key
```

You are assigning a new empty array to `$output[$keys]` every time, meaning what you have pushed into that array in the current loop iteration, will get thrown away in the next iteration where `$keys` has the same value again.

You don't need to explicitly initialize further array "dimensions" to store data into them. Just initialize `$output = [];` as an empty array *before* the loop; then you can add anything below at any level via simple assignment, regardless of whether that level / path / whatever you want to call it, already exists or not - PHP will create it, if necessary.

Replace these two lines

```
$output[$keys] = [];  //Creating key 
array_push($output[$keys],$row);
```

with just

```
$output[$keys][] = $row;
```

(Why is `$keys` named in plural to begin with? This is a single vaue, not multiple ones. And that "helper variable" isn't really necessary to begin with - you can replace the *whole* loop body you had, with just `$output[$row['Cat_name']][] = $row;` - if you *want* to; if the other version with the helper variable is more readable to you, that's fine as well.)

---

One more thing,

```
foreach($row as $row){
```

You should avoid using the same variable name for two different things like that. It does not directly affect what happens inside the foreach loop here - but it will change what `row` contains *after* your loop, so in case you still need access to that original array of data afterwards, you should not *overwrite* it here.

Comment: I am assigning keys to remember...

Comment: i need format like
{
    "response": [
        {
            "category_id": "1",
            "name": "Cat",
            "wallpapers": [
                {
                    "start": "2021-12-01 00:35:00",
                    "episode_num": ""
                },
                {
                    "start": "2021-12-01 00:40:00",
                    "episode_num": ""
                },
            ]
        }
        } 
 ]
}

Comment: You have not even shown us _proper_ input data yet, that could lead to any such result. Those `start` values for example, where are those coming from? You had already been asked in comments, to please provide a proper [mre] of your issue.

Comment: Here is the Code 
`foreach($row as $row){
$key = $row['cat_id'];
$keys = $row['Cat_name'];
 $output['response'][$keys][ ]= $row;
 $res= array($output);
 }`